# Using Delimiter and JButton to read next line

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, java.util.scanner, file-handling

newbie to java swing and action listeners.
what i am trying to is display a text file line by line, changing line when i hit a JButton. for delimiter i am using , or |
the code i have so far is:

```
next.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if (next.equals(next)) {
              {
                try{
                    File data = new File("player.txt");
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(data);

                    if (scanner != null){
                        scanner.useDelimiter(",|*");
                        if (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                            {

                                    textArea.append(scanner.nextLine() + "\n");
                            }
                        }
                            scanner.close();
                    }
              }
                catch (FileNotFoundException ex){}
              }
         }

        }//End ActionPerformed
    });//End ActionListener
```

this code is just reading the first line of the text file each time i hit the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use as delimiters `,` or `|` you should write it as

```
useDelimiter(",|\\|");
```

or

```
useDelimiter("[,\\|]");
```

Also if you want to use this delimiter you should use `scanner.next()` rather then `scanner.nextLine()`.

Lastly to read entire content of file you should use `while (scanner.hasNext())` rather then `if (scanner.hasNextLine())`, or create scanner outside of `ActionListener` so your action could read next line with each button-click (now your ActionListener creates new Scanner with each button click so it starts reading file from beginning).

Comment: thank you this solved my problem with the delimiter. What i also want to do is display it just one line at a time.as in line one on its own then when i click the button it just displays line two and so on. The way it is now it displays all lines at once when i click the button

Comment: In that case you would have to crate Scanner object outside of `ActionListener`. Maybe create `Scanner scanner;` field in your class, initialize it in constructor and then use it in `ActionListener`.

Comment: i added `Scanner scanner;` out side the `ActionListener` but it still gave me the same result.

Comment: @Dobby Didn't you remove `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(data);` from ActionListener?

Comment: i have removed it now and added it out side the listener. now it will read all the file once and then give me an error in the cmd window when i click the button again.. what am i doing wrong?? sorry for all the questions @Pshemo but i am a newbie to swing and gui's

Comment: @Dobby Take a look at this example http://pastebin.com/57V7YGHL I am not sure if it is 100% correct but it should give you some general idea of how you can read one element of file with every click.